# Compilation problems BootCamp Miktex. Missing \item perhaps

Tags: errors, miktex, windows

I have a document which currently compiles on my pure windows machine but I have problems compiling on a mac which uses bootcamp and runs windows 8.1. I get the same error at strange places in the main document,missing \item perhaps. These errors appear at empty spaces and spaces were there are text and is very random.

I cant figure out what the problem is at all because it runs on my other computer with the same miktex and texworks. I use dropbox so I share the files.

Any one with maybe some of the same problems on BootCamp and windows 8.1?

Comment: add `\listfiles` to your document preamble and then compare the file list in the log on each machine. Probably an old version of a package on one of th emachines.

Comment: Ok i see that glossayr package now breaks, but cant seem to find what breaks. Any ideas?

Comment: Since making guesses is pretty hard without any evidence it would be good, if you could post your code.

Comment: @vonGohren hard to say as you have provided no example, but basically just update your tex system on whichever machine has the older package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it was as easy as the glossary packaged had to be updated, and because of the update, the .glo files related has to be deleted to be able to reset the enviroment.

Nothing more